# How deeper layers learn from previous layers feature maps in Conv nets

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, convolution, biological-neural-network

I read a lot about convnets but still I miss a important part.

Let's say we have a conv2D layer with 32 filters:

I understand that these filters weights are initialize randomly in the beginning and during training process these filters are formed.
So at first layer they start to detect edges.

And now after pooling we have another conv layer(let's say 32 filters again) which will apply filters on the result of the previous layer.

**So layer 2 will apply 32 filters on ANY of these 32 outputs from first layer.**
I saw so many examples of these feature maps: first layer produce pictures of edges, on the next layer pictures are forms, ear, nose and so on.
My question is how is this possible?

**If layer 2 apply filters on layer 1 result and layer 1 result are edges then how you get a form from a edge?**

**I clearly miss something here, please help me understand how is possible every next layer in conv net producing richer features like forms, eye , face in case it uses production from previous layer where features are just lines and edges?**

Is there some information merging during the process I'm missing or it's something more?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example: let's say you try to distinguish simple geometric forms. E.g. rectangles from diamonds.

On the first layer you have various edge detectors. Some fire when they detect horizontal edges, some when they detect vertical edges and some others when they see diagonal edges.

The second layer can now combine those inputs to more complicated shapes.
So one filter/detector will fire if on the first layer vertical and horizontal edges are detected. This is the filter for the rectangle.

Another filter will fire when the first layers tells that it detected diagonal edges. This is the filter for the diamonds.

You might make yourself familiar with dimensions of in and output of a convolutional layer.

```
Input = W1xW1xD1

Output:
W2 = (W1 - F + 2P)/S + 1
D2 = K
```

`Terminology: K = Number of Filters, F= Spatial Size of Filter, P=ZeroPadding, S=Stride`

You might find this helpful:

https://adeshpande3.github.io/adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner's-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks/

[http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#fc)

Comment: So you say that second layer combine somehow the result of the first layer? I thought that first layer will produce let say 32 images and second will apply filters on each of them and second layer output will be 32x32 ... 1024 images

Comment: Yes, the second layer filters performs convolutions on the results of the first layer.

Comment: The Filters are applied to all channels of the previous layer. Have a look at this [demo gif](http://cs231n.github.io/assets/conv-demo/index.html) from [here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#convolutional-layer). If you have a look at the gif you will se that information from all channels are combined.

Comment: Sorry I still do not understand.Let's say I have a picture of a mouse.Let's say first layer create 32 images.Some of these images will be edges, other lines. So now let's take only one of them , some edge as an input of the second layer. How this second layer applying new 32 filters on only this "edge " picture will extract richer form.I can not find clear example or explanation are these products from previous layer combine somehow in the next. It seems like they are processed separately which actually confuse me. If they are combined somehow: yes that makes sense, but I can not find example

Comment: I really recommend you to use the formula I provided above. Maybe try to understand alexnet. Additionaly you might have a look at this [interactive visualization](http://scs.ryerson.ca/~aharley/vis/conv/) it is documented [here](http://scs.ryerson.ca/~aharley/vis/)

Comment: The formula above calculate the dimensions of the output image but that do not answer my question which is: If next layer uses for input the output of the previous layer WITHOUT combining anything , just apply convolution on each image, then seems impossible to obtain richer form from a simple edge. If there is some combining of these simple edges and lines before filtering that is a different story, but I can not find clear explanation on this process. Thanks about source, I'll check it out.I do understand the convolution process but I clearly miss something.

Comment: A 2d-convolution filter takes all depth channels from the previous layer as input. Each channel from the previous layer corresponds to one filter in the previous layer. 

If you have 5 Filters in the first layer and 1 filter in the second it combines the information from all 5 filters from the first layer.

Comment: I think I got it. They way that a net learn from many samples, the next layer filter learn from samples produce by previous filter. So there is no combining but just because the filter get through each on of them it learns its weights from each one and that's way it produce mixed product. It is like if you learn net with images of cats and dogs and use equal label (x) for them and after that if you pass a image of something that looks like a cat and dog in the same time , net will classify it as x. Am I getting is correct?